# Square root approximation calculator

Tags: c

`do` / `while` loop is infinite and will not break or return proper number, however when printing the variable `last_guess` inside of the loop, I infinitely get the correct value I want to return.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double square_root(double number, double last_guess) {
    double new_guess = 1;

    if (number >= 0) {
        do {
            new_guess = 0.5 * (last_guess + number / last_guess);

            last_guess = new_guess;

        } while (new_guess > 0.005);
    } else {
        printf("Not a positive integer.");
    }

    if (new_guess < 0.005)  {
        last_guess = roundf(last_guess * 100.0) / 100.0;
        return last_guess;
    }
}

int main() {
    double number, new_guess = 1.0;
    double last_guess = 1.0;

    printf("enter: ");
    scanf("%lf", &number);

    printf("enter: ");
    scanf("%lf", &last_guess);

    double final_value = square_root(number, last_guess);

    printf("%d", final_value);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `do { ... } while (new_guess > 0.005)` means you can only find small square roots! If the root is `2` (or `3.14`, ...) you will be stuck inside the loop for ever.

Comment: You need to actually return a value from `square_root` through all paths too .... and `printf("%f", final_value); // %f not %d`

Comment: Use `(fabs(new_guess - last_guess) > 0.005)` and rearrange the loop.

Comment: @pmg ok but how do i fix that

Comment: hehe veddersboy, the point is that once you find where **and why** the code is stuck in a loop, it becomes easy to solve the issue ... possibly using the hint given by @WeatherVane

Comment: Aside: I don't think you really need to input to `last_guess`. Using the number itself will converge quickly, and you don't need the second argument for `square_root()` either. Just start with `double last_guess = number;` in the function.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate until the difference between successive guesses is small enough, not until the last guess is below the threshold.

Furthermore, you should use `%e`, `%f` or `%g` to convert a `double` value with `printf`, not `%d`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double square_root(double number, double last_guess) {
    double new_guess = 1;

    if (number >= 0) {
        for (;;) {
            new_guess = 0.5 * (last_guess + number / last_guess);
            if (fabs(new_guess - last_guess) <= 0.00001 * new_guess)
                break;
            last_guess = new_guess;
        }
        return new_guess;
   } else {
        printf("Not a positive integer.");
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {

    double number, new_guess = 1.0;
    double last_guess = 1.0;

    printf("enter: ");
    scanf("%lf", &number);

    printf("enter: ");
    scanf("%lf", &last_guess);

    double final_value = square_root(number, last_guess);

    printf("%g\n", final_value);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "iterate until the difference between successive guesses is small enough" is a good idea, yet `fabs(new_guess - last_guess) < 0.005` is an insufficient test as "small enough" is relative to the magnitude .  It is poor when `number` is a small value like 1e-100 and may not converge to a stable  value when `number` is large like `1e100`.  A relative compare would be better, perhaps `pow(new_guess - last_guess,2) < 0.005*number`.  Even with that, code deserves testing.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I agree 100%, I amended the answer, but the updated test  is still not foolproof, especially for very small values of `number`.

Comment: As with such iterative methods and floating-point: the `y[n + 1] = f(y[n], ...)` is the easy part.  "iterate until the difference between successive guesses is small enough" is the tricky part.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, floating point functions deserve a test harness.

This one tests a variation of [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77398669/2410359) good answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

double square_root(double number, double last_guess) {
  double new_guess = 1.0;

  if (number >= 0) {
    // Avoid infinite loops
    for (int iteration = 0; iteration < DBL_MAX_EXP + DBL_MANT_DIG; iteration++) {
      new_guess = 0.5 * (last_guess + number / last_guess);
      if (fabs(new_guess - last_guess) <= 0.00001 * new_guess || new_guess == 0.0) {
        break;
      }
      // printf("%3d number:%24.17g lg:%24.17g ng:%24.17g\n", iteration, number, last_guess, new_guess);
      last_guess = new_guess;
    }
    return new_guess;
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Not a positive integer.");
    return 0;
  }
}

void test(double x) {
  double y0 = sqrt(x);
  double y1 = square_root(x, 1);
  double difference = y1 - y0;
  double relative_error = difference ? difference / y0 : 0.0;
  printf("x:%24.17g y0:%24.17g y1:%24.17g rerror:%g\n", x, y0, y1,
      relative_error);
}

int main(void) {
  const double x[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1e100, DBL_MAX, 1e-100, DBL_MIN, DBL_TRUE_MIN, 0};
  size_t n = sizeof x / sizeof x[0];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    test(x[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
x:                       1 y0:                       1 y1:                       1 rerror:0
x:                       2 y0:      1.4142135623730951 y1:      1.4142135623746899 rerror:1.12764e-12
x:                       3 y0:      1.7320508075688772 y1:      1.7320508075688772 rerror:0
x:                       4 y0:                       2 y1:      2.0000000000000022 rerror:1.11022e-15
x:                  1e+100 y0:  1.0000000000000001e+50 y1:  1.0000000000002003e+50 rerror:2.00215e-13
x: 1.7976931348623157e+308 y0: 1.3407807929942596e+154 y1: 1.3407807929942936e+154 rerror:2.54241e-14
x:                  1e-100 y0:                   1e-50 y1:  1.0000000000002005e-50 rerror:2.00475e-13
x: 2.2250738585072014e-308 y0: 1.4916681462400413e-154 y1: 1.4916681462400791e-154 rerror:2.53131e-14
x: 4.9406564584124654e-324 y0: 2.2227587494850775e-162 y1: 2.2227587494851337e-162 rerror:2.53131e-14
x:                       0 y0:                       0 y1:                       0 rerror:0
```